# Removing duplicates

Tags: deduplication

i've got plenty of those duplicates:

```
2017-11-22_3083_smokey_brights_-_come_to_terms.mp3
2017-12-01-Smokey_Brights_-_Come_To_Terms.mp3
```

How can I keep only one of each ?
Unfortunately, their md5sum differ.

My best attempt is

```
ls *mp3 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | rev | sort | uniq -w 30 -d | rev
```

targeting the files ending with 30 or more same characters.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You tagged [tag:sed], [tag:awk]. `sed` processes text, so does `awk`. Is it about lines of text? or about files (their content)? If the latter, is it about mp3 format only? What is your OS? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: this is indeed not related to `awk` nor `sed`. Thanks for your advice. And my os is GNU/Linux (Debian).

Comment: If their MD5s differ at the very least their tags are different. Did you check whenever they are the same length? if all of those files match that pattern just look for 4 numbers in a row and remove them them. if there is a file with that name already you got a duplicate. There is a lot of information missing about what you already did and what structure those files got. Whenever they are spread out or in the same location and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, their md5sum differ"

then are they really duplicates? And how would you know which to delete without listening to them?

I would advise you to get a [duplicate file finder](https://www.techspot.com/article/1648-delete-duplicate-files/) and set it to just show duplicates rather than auto-delete, so that you can listen to them and decide.

Or, if that is too much trouble, set it to auto-delete all but the newest, largest, whatever.

Rather than just a duplicate file finder, consider a duplicate music file finder.

[This page](https://www.geckoandfly.com/8763/how-to-remove-duplicate-mp3-from-itunes/) says, for instance

> Similarity rapidly scans your music collection and shows all duplicate music files you may have. The comparison powered by “acoustic fingerprint” technology considers the actual contents of files, not just tags or filenames, and thus ensures the extreme accuracy of similarity estimation. Moreover, the comparison isn’t dependent of music file format; the application supports almost every file format in full. Works great on Microsoft’s Windows 10 and Apple’s macOS.
>
> Thanks to 3-level analysis Similarity offers a uniquely high level of duplicate detection. It supports MP3, AAC, M4A, WMA, OGG, WAV, FLAC, APE, WV, MPC, OPUS, TTA formats and is able to find similar compositions among all of them. In fact, the list of supported formats is truly unlimited due to the support of third-party codecs. Similarity has a built-in tag editor, a spectrum analyzer, a sonogram analyzer, an automatic tag converter, acceleration of computing with the OpenCL technology (supports modern nVidia and AMD video cards) and many other cool features.

[Similarity](http://www.similarityapp.com/) is free, so why not give it a try?